# What does this suggest? "…caused by increased afterload and fluid redistribution to the lungs in the absence or with minimal fluid accumulation"

Tags: grammar, meaning

> Because of their mechanisms of action, i.v vasodilators may be more
> effective than diuretics in those patients whose acute pulmonary
> oedema is caused by *increased afterload(a)* **and** **fluid redistribution to
> the lungs(b)* ***in the absence or with minimal fluid accumulation(c)*.***

What does this sentence suggest? How should I interpret it? Is it:

(a+b) +  c applied to these two?

or

a+ b (c applied to b)

The whole text is here: [2021 ESC Guidelines for the diagnosis and treatment of acute and chronic heart failure](https://academic.oup.com/eurheartj/article/42/36/3599/6358045?login=false#305163157)

> Intravenous vasodilators, namely nitrates or nitroprusside
> (Supplementary Table 21), dilate venous and arterial vessels leading
> to a reduction in venous return to the heart, less congestion, lower
> afterload, increased stroke volume and consequent relief of symptoms.
> Nitrates act mainly on peripheral veins whereas nitroprusside is more
> a balanced arterial and venous dilator.474,475 Because of their
> mechanisms of action, i.v. vasodilators may be more effective than
> diuretics in those patients whose acute pulmonary oedema is caused by
> increased afterload and fluid redistribution to the lungs in the
> absence or with minimal fluid accumulation.427,476–478 However, two
> recent randomized trials comparing usual care with early intensive and
> sustained vasodilation failed to show a beneficial effect of i.v.
> vasodilators vs. high-dose diuretics.479,480 No recommendation
> favouring a regimen based on vasodilator treatment vs. usual care can
> thus be given, to date.

Comment: What is the source of the quoted sentence, please? If possible, please provide a link so further context can be checked. Even if a link is not possible, author and title should always be provided to attribute quotes used here on ELL.SE.

Comment: The text is awkward to read, and the final part lacks a preposition, and some punctuation, in my opinion - it would read better as... 'i.v vasodilators may be more effective than diuretics in those patients whose acute pulmonary oedema is caused by (a) increased afterload and (b) fluid redistribution to the lungs (c) in the absence **of**, or with minimal, fluid accumulation. I wonder if it was badly edited, typeset, or translated?

Comment: I edited with the whole text. It could be badly edited; I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Thanks for the added context dn the link. I still think that the  "absence of fluid retention" applies to both previous conditions, but the sentence is ambiguous. One might need to read the other papers mentioned in the footnotes to be sure.

Comment: I agree with you. It is intented to give the meaning you've mentioned. I appreciate the effort ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence means that if (a) **and** (b) are true, but (c) (fluid accumulation) is not the case, then "i.v vasodilators may be more effective than diuretics".

I am not clear what you mean by your two pseudo mathematical formulae, and in particular what you mean by "c applied to b".

Comment: I thought it was saying that 'fluid redistribution in the absence of fluid accumulation' By saying b+c, I meant b and c are linked to each other. So you are stating that this is not the case. Thank you for the help ^^

Comment: @Eren Yucel  That is not how I read it. But it might have been intended in that way. Additional context would be needed to be certain.